# Manually Sending A New Order Email In Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I would like to programmically fire a new order email, so it looks the same as the standard Woo Commerce email template.

I am using the WC_Email_New_Order class, so I can made adjustment to the order object before the email is constructed from it.

Here in some test code, I am firing it the wp_head hook for now, just for testing purposes.

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {
    include('wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php');
    include('wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-new-order.php');

    $adminEmail = new WC_Email_New_Order();

    $id = 1564; // order
    $order = new WC_Order($id);

    $adminEmail->trigger( null, $order );

});
```

This works partially... I get the email with the correct subject line, however the body of the email just says...

```
You’ve received the following order from Dave Peterson:
```

How do I get the rest of the email template to fire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply try use the following in any hooked function with a dynamic variable `$order_id`:

```
// Get the WC_Email_New_Order object
$email_new_order = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];

// Sending the new Order email notification for an $order_id (order ID)
$email_new_order->trigger( $order_id );
```

This normally will fire the New Order Woocommerce notification for the current order ID.

> **Since WooCommerce 5+:** [Allow re-sending New Order Notification in WooCommerce 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604256/allow-re-sending-new-order-notification-in-woocommerce-5/66604522#66604522)

Answer (score -2):

You just need an order object to trigger new order emails. `WC()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order->get_id(), $order );`